# Something is closing Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, debug

On my machine, every time I open Chrome, it opens for about 2 seconds then closes. It doesn't become unresponsive, or come up with the "Woah Chrome has Crashed" message, it simply closes, as if something is killing all the `chrome.exe` processes.

As part of my companies IT policy, I have a Internet Filter installed that I can't make changes to, and it's managed remotely by a 3rd party. I cannot disable this program short of re-installing windows. Although it's primarily an Internet Filter, I know it can block programs. I'm pointing the finger at it for messing up Chrome, because the way Chrome closes is exactly the way it blocks the programs that are on it's blacklist. Basically as soon as it detects a process that it thinks shouldn't run, it kills it.

So I emailed the 3rd party IT guys and told them that their program is blocking Chrome, although in the Web App Chrome is not listed as a blocked app. They told me that no way is their program responsible for this. "After all, its an Internet Filter. Why would it block the program that accesses the internet?"

So basically what I'm after is: Is there anyway to use a "debugger" or something to watch all the processes, and see that user started `chrome.exe`, then `xxx.exe` or `xxx` service sent kill command to `chrome.exe`? Because armed with that I could then determine if it's really the internet filter or not, then proceed from there.

Comment: Simple way to verify.  Change the name of the chrome executable.  If it still crashes it could still be this filter program, but not because its blocking the execution of Chrome.exe, but for some other reason linked to an incompatibility with Chrome.

Comment: Good Point - I changed it to `notepad.exe` and it worked. Thanks, I had forgotten that most of my games have strange names ;)

Comment: If Chrome works with a new name it means that the filtering software is blocking chrome.exe, it also means you got a less then truthful answer.