# Why is Chrome closing within 10 seconds of opening?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Last week my Chrome started closing for no apparent reason. There is no crash message or anything, it just closes in a random amount of time within 10 seconds of being opened.

I've checked the Chrome logs, and the non-verbose version has nothing while the verbose version has a lot of stuff that looks unrelated. Nothing really looks like it has to do with the closing.

I've tried:

- Launching Chrome with every "disable" command line argument
- Launching Chrome in Safe Mode w/ Networking
- Running Malwarebytes and  SuperAntiSpyware (which found nothing)
- Running Chromium instead (same behavior)
- Uninstalling/reinstalling including removing browsing data and manually deleting Chrome's data directory, and using Revo Uninstaller
- Multiple system reboots
- Checked for Windows updates applied when issue started but there was nothing recent
- Checked Task Manager to see if there was any job that might be shutting it down, didn't see anything that would
- Starting Chrome after renaming the executable per this thread: [Something is closing Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1009237/something-is-closing-chrome)

I'm on the Windows 10 Pro 1803 build (OS build 17134.885.) There is a newer build of Win10 but Windows Update says it's not ready for my PC yet so not sure if that would help.

The only other thing I can think of to do is try downloading the Chromium source and running in debug mode, but I figured I'd ask here first.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?